WPF: how to create a re-usable Button that has a different tooltip when it is enabled or disabled
How can you create a re-usable WPF Button that has a different tooltip when it is enabled or disabled?
What I achieved so far almost works.
Except that the enabled button doesn't show the enabled tooltip.
When toggling the enabled state, the tooltip does show disabled.
Maybe this is caused by the EnabledToolTip is not yet initialized when DataTriggers are initialized?
The weird thing is that doing a xaml hot-reload when debugging, even without changes, fixes the issue and the 'enabled' and disabled tooltip show as expected.
I tried setting ToolTip in the EnabledToolTip en DisabledToolTip setters, but this resulted in always showing the enabled tooltip.
ButtonDualToolTip.xaml
<Button x:Class="ButtonDualToolTip"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=EnabledToolTip}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DisabledToolTip}" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>

ButtonDualToolTip.xaml.cs
public partial class ButtonDualToolTip : Button
{
   public ButtonDualToolTip()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public string EnabledToolTip
   {
      get { return (string)GetValue(EnabledToolTipProperty); }
      set { SetValue(EnabledToolTipProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledToolTipProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EnabledToolTip), typeof(string), typeof(Field), new PropertyMetadata());

   public string DisabledToolTip
   {
      get { return (string)GetValue(DisabledToolTipProperty); }
      set { SetValue(DisabledToolTipProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledToolTipProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DisabledToolTip), typeof(string), typeof(Field), new PropertyMetadata());
}

Usage example
<CheckBox x:Name="toolTipController"
          Content="Button enabled" />

<usercontrols:ButtonDualToolTip Content="Test"
                                EnabledToolTip="enabled"
                                DisabledToolTip="disabled"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=toolTipController, Path=IsChecked}" />


There is already a way to make tooltips show when the control is disabled.  All you have to do is set the attached property ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True".  As for making the tooltip show different values based on whether the controls is enabled, I typically use a value converter that I wrote that takes a boolean argument and returns one of two user-specified values based on whether it is true or false.  Then I bind it to the IsEnabled property of the control

Buttons don't exist in a vacuum. This "enabling / disabling" is related to properties in the model; and that's what you should be binding to in terms of "enabled / not enabled" and  the corresponding "tool tip". Whether the button exists or not, there is a "state" in the model that "would" be reflected in the button; if it did exist. That particular "state" is not inherent in the button. The button is simply a "mini-view" into a bigger picture.
